# How to check what is after hyphen with jQuery's "Attribute Contains Prefix Selector"

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I've got some html like:

```
<a class="link" href="#>link</a>
<a class="link-0" href="#>link</a>
<a class="link-1 enabled" href="#>link</a>
<a class="link-2" href="#>link</a>
```

I can select all of those links by:

```
$('[class|="link"]');
```

but I find it very difficult to check what is after hyphen, I think about getting classes by `attr('class')` splitting with `split(' ')` and checking each class, if it starts with "link" and splitting again with `split('-')`.

Anyone knows better way to do this?

Comment: That probably depends on what you want to do with the second part. Do you want to extract and process it or what do you want to do?

Comment: Personally I'd just use class "link" (which will be faster to look for anyway) and then store the additional qualifier in a "data-" attribute (like "data-link"), unless you need the "link-0" etc. for styling. In that case, I'd give it two classes: "link" and "link-n", and then use a regex to find the "link-n" class and strip out the "n".

Answer (score 0):

Interesting that other variations of this selector doesn't match it - perhaps a bug with jquery with hyphens.

```
$('a[class^="link-"]')
```

Turns out others work to, just not "word selectors"

```
$('a[class*="link-"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var matches = element.attr("class").match(/^link-?(\d*)$/);
var whichLink = matches[1];
```